# Why does the Java ByteBuffer.getLong()/getInt()-Method not return the expected int-number?

Tags: java

the following Class reads a long-value from a textfile into a buffer. That value is used it to change the position of the FileChannel, where it reads another value into the buffer. Via the getInt()-Method, the last value is printed out as an int.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel;
import java.nio.file.OpenOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class ReadChannelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path file2 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\datafile.txt");
        OpenOption rd = StandardOpenOption.READ;

        try( SeekableByteChannel in2 = FileChannel.open(file2, rd )){
            ByteBuffer buf =  ByteBuffer.allocate(64);

            in2.position(0);
            in2.read(buf);
            buf.rewind();


            long pos = buf.getLong();
            System.out.println("Read position: " + pos);

            in2.position(pos);
            buf.rewind();
            in2.read(buf);
            System.out.print("The int value: "+buf.getInt());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The console shows the following output:

```
Read position: 3756037515073552384    
The int value: 874520608
```

The datafile.txt looks like this:

```
4   89
```

I expected the 4 to be read into the ByteBuffer and used it to change the position of the Channel to 4. But, eventually, *807411744* instead of *8* is printed out. Why is that? Why is the pos-value *3756037515073552384* instead of *4*?

Thank you very much.

-mrFunkus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getLong()` reads the first 8 bytes from the `ByteBuffer` and converts it to a `long`

It *does not parse text* to numbers. See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getLong()

You might want to use a `Scanner`

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you. But just for the sake of knowledge: What does the FileChannel parse the input-text into? Is the output in my post some kind of RAM-adress?

Comment: `FileChannel` does not parse, it helps to reads bytes using OS mechanics, IIRC.